# Can I connect to SolrServer via RMI rather than Http?

Tags: java, http, solr, jndi

I have a Solr server, that stores some data. I had to write a custom processor inserted into a processor chain that verifies some things (so it goes like this UpdateRequest => CustomProcessor => RunUpdateProcessor => LogUpdateProcessor ).

To verify some data I need to extract a document from Solr - right now I create an instance of CommonHttpSolrServer, connect to my Solr (which is standing on the same JBoss) and perform the search.

What I want is to have some more local way to perform a search, like jndi-lookup for some bean containing Solr Core or Searcher, something that wouldn't need to travel via remote protocol.

Is there a way to do that, or am I stuck with Http?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, see [EmbeddedSolr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/EmbeddedSolr) (read also the warnings)